# How to containerize a Java application with user-defined reference classes in Docker?

Tags: java, docker, containers

I tried using these lines of code in my docker file, but I receive error when I try to compile and build it:

```
FROM openjdk:7
COPY . /usr/src/myjava
WORKDIR /usr/src/myjava
RUN javac Clock.java // User-Defined Reference Class
RUN javac AlarmClock.java // User-defined Reference Class
RUN javac Program.java
CMD ["java", "Clock"]`
CMD ["java", "AlarmClock"]
CMD ["java", "Program"]
```

This is the error I encounter when I try the `docker build .` command:

```
C:\Users\EXOUSIA\Desktop\DockerFile>docker build .
[+] Building 3.2s (8/10)
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile 0.0s 
=> => transferring dockerfile: 253B  0.0s
=> [internal] load .dockerignore  0.0s
                                                                                                                           => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:9                                                                                                       1.5s

  => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                  0.0s

 => => transferring context: 6.31kB                                                                                                                                0.0s

  => CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:9@sha256:0e48e7e79d9e5637ee5d9c4a4fa2615c7bde69390aab06f7105eb4a8ebec8383 0.0s  

  => [2/6] COPY . /usr/src/myjava                                                                                                                                   0.0s

 => [3/6] WORKDIR /usr/src/myjava                                                                                                                                  0.1s

  => ERROR [4/6] RUN javac Program.java                                                                                                                             1.4s

 ------
 [4/6] RUN javac Program.java:

 #8 1.304 Program.java:29: error: cannot access AlarmClock

 #8 1.304     static AlarmClock cl = new AlarmClock();

 #8 1.305            ^

#8 1.305   bad source file: ./AlarmClock.java

 #8 1.305     file does not contain class AlarmClock

 #8 1.305     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.

 #8 1.306 1 error      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 ------

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c javac Program.java]: exit code: 1

 C:\Users\EXOUSIA\Desktop\DockerFile>
```

When I try to compile the classes, error shows:

```
C:\Users\EXOUSIA\Desktop\DockerFile>javac Program.java 

Program.java:29: error: cannot find symbol

static AlarmClock cl = new AlarmClock();
           ^
symbol:   class AlarmClock

location: class Program

Program.java:29: error: cannot find symbol

static AlarmClock cl = new AlarmClock();
                             ^
 symbol:   class AlarmClock

location: class Program

2 errors

C:\Users\EXOUSIA\Desktop\DockerFile>
```

**AlarmClock.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class AlarmClock extends Clock{
public int hourAlarm;
public int minuteAlarm;
public int secondAlarm;


// constructor
public AlarmClock() {
    super();
    hourAlarm = 0;
    minuteAlarm = 0;
    secondAlarm = 0;
}

// Mutator Methods
public void setHourAlarm(int hourA) {
    if((hourA >= 0) && (hourA <= 24)) {
        hourAlarm = hourA;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid hour alarm");
    }
}

public void setMinuteAlarm(int minuteA){
    if((minuteA >= 0) && (minuteA <= 24)) {
        minuteAlarm = minuteA;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid minute alarm");
    }
}

public void setSecondAlarm(int secondA){
    if((secondA >= 0) && (secondA <= 24)) {
        secondAlarm = secondA;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid second alarm");
    }
}


// Accessor Methods
public int getHourAlarm(){
    return hourAlarm;
}

public int getMinuteAlarm() {
    return minuteAlarm;
}

public int getSecondAlarm(){
    return secondAlarm;
}


// Add time methods with Overloads
public int addHour(int incValue) {
    if(hourAlarm + incValue > 12) {
        hourAlarm = 0;
        return hourAlarm;
    } else {
        return hourAlarm += incValue;
    }
}

public int addHour() {
    hourAlarm++;
    if(hourAlarm > 12) {
        hourAlarm = 0;
        return hourAlarm;
    }
    return hourAlarm;
}

public int addMinute(int incValue) {
    minuteAlarm++;
    if(minuteAlarm + incValue > 59) {
        minuteAlarm = 0;
        return minuteAlarm;
    }
    return minuteAlarm;
}

public int addMinute() {
    minuteAlarm++;
    if(minuteAlarm > 59) {
        minuteAlarm = 0;
        return minuteAlarm;
    }
    return minuteAlarm;
}

public int addSeconds(int incValue) {
    secondAlarm++;
    if(secondAlarm + incValue > 59) {
        secondAlarm = 0;
        return secondAlarm;
    }
    return secondAlarm;

}

public int addSeconds() {
    secondAlarm++;
    if(secondAlarm > 59) {
        secondAlarm = 0;
        return secondAlarm;
    }
    return secondAlarm;

}

// Sets the alarm time from the input of the user passed in the param
public String setAlarmTime(int hour, int minute, int second) {
    hourAlarm = hour;
    minuteAlarm = minute;
    secondAlarm = second;

    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("00");
    return "Alarm is set to: " + fmt.format(hour) + ":" + 
fmt.format(minute) + ":" + fmt.format(second);
}

// Triggers the alarm if the time and the alarm time is the same/equal
public void triggerAlarm() {
    if((getHour() == hourAlarm) && (getMinute() == minuteAlarm) && 
(getSecond() == secondAlarm) ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Alert! Alert! Alarm is on!");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Adding the error will help to understand the problem

Comment: @GuillaumeBarré I've added the errors.

Comment: Can you show `AlarmClock.java`?

Comment: @dan1st added it

Comment: Can you try `javac Program.java AlarmClock.java`?

Comment: @dan1st It compiles, but when I try to run the docker build . command. It still shows the same error.

Comment: I meant to use `RUN javac Program.java AlarmClock.java` in the Dockerfile instead of using both seperately.

Comment: @dan1st Tried it, it works! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I formatted the Dockerfile like this and it didn't show any errors. Also I have removed the JOptionMessageDialog parts and changed it into Scanner instead. It seems like it doesn't support GUI features:

```
FROM openjdk:9

COPY . /usr/src/myjava

WORKDIR /usr/src/myjava

RUN javac Program.java AlarmClock.java Clock.java

CMD ["java", "Program", "AlarmClock", "Clock"]
```